# Unpacking multiple values from a nested dictionary in one line "pythonically"

Tags: python, dictionary, nested, unpack

Suppose I have a nested dictionary that looks like this:

```
numbers = { 
    'one': {"square": "one", "cube": "one"},
    'two': {"square": "four", "cube": "eight"},
    'three': {"square": "nine", "cube": "twenty-seven"},
    'four': {"square": "sixteen", "cube": "sixty-four"}
}
```

and I want to unpack the squares and cubes into lists.   I could do this:

```
squares = [n["square"] for n in numbers.values()]
cubes = [n["cube"] for n in numbers.values()]
```

but that doesn't seem very satisfactory for the repetitive code.   I could also bring in numpy and do this:

```
import numpy
squares_array, cubes_array = numpy.array([(n["square"],n["cube"]) for n in numbers.values()]).T
```

and that neatly unpacks everything into numpy arrays, but it looks a little unsatisfactory since I shouldn't need numpy to do this, and taking the transpose at the end is a little weird in my highly subjective opinion.   It doesn't seem "pythonic" to me.

So the question is how can I do this in one line without numpy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
squares, cubes = zip(*[(n["square"], n["cube"]) for n in numbers.values()])
```

Comment: Minor variation for fun. Add `from operator import itemgetter` to the top of the file, then do: `squares, cubes = zip(*map(itemgetter('square', 'cube'), numbers.values()))` (change to `squares, cubes = map(list, zip(*map(itemgetter('square', 'cube'), numbers.values())))` if the results must be `list`, not `tuple`).

Answer (score 0):

You could use `zip` and a iterator:

```
squares, cubes = map(list, zip(*(d.values() for d in numbers.values())))
```

If there are more keys or a different order, specify them manually:

```
squares, cubes = map(list, zip(*([d['square'], d['cube']]
                                 for d in numbers.values())))
```

output:

```
>>> squares
['one', 'four', 'nine', 'sixteen']

>>> cubes
['one', 'eight', 'twenty-seven', 'sixty-four']
```

Comment: Note: This solution is *very* brittle (and will not work at all prior to CPython 3.6 as an implementation detail, 3.7 as a language guarantee). If the `dict`s aren't uniformly defined with the `'square'` key always inserted before `'cube'`, and *only* those two keys, the result will be incorrect. It works for the OP's example input, but I wouldn't rely on it.

Comment: @ShadowRanger I imagine this is the assumption, if not one can specify the keys to keep (see update)